# DateFormat - Allowable formats?

Tags: basic4android

I have the following code returning the time in a 24 hour format like "13:10:23"

```
DateTime.DateFormat = "h:mm a"
now = DateTime.Now                              
t = DateTime.Time(now)                          
lblCurrentTime.Text = t
```

But I'd like to have the format in `hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds`

Unfortunately, the link to the supported formats from this page is broken..

http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/wiki/index.php/DateTime

Could anyone please suggest how to use DateTime.Dateformat to return a time value to millisecond resolution?

---

Thank you, but I'm afraid it's still returning time in the format: "23:11:09"

Perhaps my variables are incorrect?

```
Sub Time_tick                                       
Dim now As Long                              
Dim t As String

DateTime.DateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SS"
now = DateTime.Now                              
t = DateTime.Time(now)                          
lblCurrentTime.Text = t 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Try: "HH:mm:ss:SS"

Note that you should use DateTime.TimeFormat and not DateFormat.

Comment: That link is now 404'd.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following ?

```
DateTime.DateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SS"
```